# Flutter, Rooted Device. File Copy Permission denied

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using the `root_access` and `permission_handler` packages in a Flutter app to copy a file from the data folder to the storage.  Although all required permissions are granted, I receive the following error: **`OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13`**. This occurs on an Android device that is rooted and running Flutter version 3.7.11. and an Android SDK version 33.0.2. In the `AndroidManifest` File, I added `uses-permission`.  I am able to copy from storage to storage without any issues.

The code snippet that causes the error is as follows, as it attempts to copy file `/data/file.txt` to `/storage/emulated/0/documents/file.txt`:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:root_access/root_access.dart';

Future<void> copyrootfile() async {
    var status = await Permission.storage.status;
    var status2 = await Permission.accessMediaLocation.status;
    var status3 = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      await Permission.storage.request();
    }
    if (!status2.isGranted) {
      await Permission.accessMediaLocation.request();
    }
    if (!status3.isGranted) {
      await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
    }
    await RootAccess.requestRootAccess;

    var rootFileText = "/data/file.txt";
    final rootFile = File(rootFileText);

    var copyTo = '/storage/emulated/0/documents/file.txt';
    if(rootFile.existsSync()){
        await rootFile.copy(copyTo);
    }
}
```

I believe I have included all necessary permissions, so I am not sure why the copy operation is failing. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

**Update**
I got this error message

```
E/flutter (27371): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to '/storage/emulated/0/Documents/file.txt', path = '/data/file.txt' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
E/flutter (27371): #0      _checkForErrorResponse (dart:io/common.dart:42:9)
E/flutter (27371): #1      _File.copy.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:339:7)
E/flutter (27371): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27371): #2      _MyHomePageState.copyrootfile (package:rootcopy/main.dart:90:7)
E/flutter (27371): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27371): #3      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:rootcopy/main.dart:130:17)
E/flutter (27371): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a solution when using **copy** function to copy file from **data** folder to **storage**. But I was able to find a solution instead.
So i used **root** package instead of **root_access**.
Package Link [root](https://pub.dev/packages/root).

The succesful code snippet is as follows.

```
  import 'dart:async';
  import 'dart:io';
  import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
  import 'package:root/root.dart';

  Future<void> copyrootfile() async {
    bool isRooted = await Root.isRooted() ?? false;
    bool isRootAvailable = await Root.isRootAvailable() ?? false;

    var status = await Permission.storage.status;
    var status2 = await Permission.accessMediaLocation.status;
    var status3 = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      await Permission.storage.request();
    }
    if (!status2.isGranted) {
      await Permission.accessMediaLocation.request();
    }
    if (!status3.isGranted) {
      await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
    }

    var rootFileText = "/data/file.txt";
    final rootFile = File(rootFileText);

    // var copyTo = '/storage/emulated/0/Documents/file.txt';
    var copyToFolder = '/storage/emulated/0/Documents/';

    if (rootFile.existsSync()) {
      String copycmd = "cp $rootFileText $copyToFolder";
      if (isRooted && isRootAvailable) {
        // Check folder Exist.
        final checkFolderExist = await Directory(copyToFolder).exists();
        if (!checkFolderExist) {
          // Create folder if not Exist.
          await Directory(copyToFolder).create(recursive: true);
        }
        // Copy using command line.
        await Root.exec(cmd: copycmd);
      }
    }
  }
```